# Reactjs click button handler with a parameter within a table parameter is always empty

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a table which contains some table rows from a server each row have a button to edit the row data; I'm trying to call click handler function with a parameter of the Id of the record unfortunately its always empty; my jsx as bellow:

```
<table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Subscription #</th>
          <th>Subscription Type</th>
          <th>Subscription Period</th>
          <th>Total Contract Amount</th>
          <th>Subscription Start Date</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {subscriptions.map((d) => {
          return (
            <tr key={d.Id}>
              <td>{d.subscriptionNumber}</td>
              <td>{d.subscriptionType}</td>
              <td>{d.subscriptionPeriod}</td>
              <td>{d.totalContractAmount}</td>
              <td>{d.subscriptionStartDate}</td>
              <td>
                <button
                  value={d.Id}
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={(e) => handleEditSubscription(e.target.value)}
                >
                  Edit
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
```

and my handler function as so :

```
  function handleEditSubscription(subsId) {
    console.log(subsId);
  }
```

how to pass the parameter correctly here? thanks in advance.

Edit : I found the solution; the Id property must be id with small letter instead, what a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`button` doesn't have `value` property. Try the following code:

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" 
  onClick={(e)=> handleEditSubscription(d.Id)}
  >
  Edit
</button>
```

Comment: Did you check if the `Id` property has value or not?